# How can I properly run a shell script automatically upon login with my mac?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, vpn, launchd

I am still learning about networking and the terminology that goes along with it; so if I misspeak, feel free to correct me.

I currently have my modem/router directly connected to my mac via an ethernet cable and I have a VPN router wired into my router modem which I am connected to on my mac via wifi. With both connections running simultaneously I have the ethernet set as primary as I don't want all of my traffic running through the VPN unnecessarily. However, when I want to access the LAN of the VPN I have to set my wifi to my primary, which can be tedious if I just quickly wish to access something. In order to make this easier, I have a bash script which will add static routes to my routing table to fix this. I have also written a .plist file with the hope of running this script automatically every time I reboot my computer. I believe the code is correct in both the bash script and the plist file, but I don't think the bash script will properly execute due to needing sudo privileges. I have read that trying to bypass this is not recommended, so I was wondering if there is either an alternative or a way to prompt me for the password upon login and for the script to run and allow the automation process to take care of the rest.

My bash script looks like this and is stored on my Desktop:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=$1

if [ $USERNAME == 'XXX' ]
 then
    route -n add 192.168.x.x/24 192.168.x.x
    route -n add 192.168.x.x/24 192.168.x.x 
    route -n add 192.168.x.x/24 192.168.x.x
elif [ $USERNAME == 'YYY']
 then
   route -n add 192.168.x.x/24 192.168.x.x 
   route -n add 192.168.x.x/24 192.168.x.x 
   route -n add 192.168.x.x/24 192.168.x.x
fi
```

My .plist file looks like this and is stored in my /Users/x/Library/LaunchAgents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.routes</string>   
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/x/Desktop/Routes.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Right now, this process is not currently working; whether that is because of an error in my code, or because of a privilege issue, I am not sure. When I run the bash script directly from the CLI with sudo privileges it does work properly. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `~/Desktop/Routes.sh` to `/Users/Austin/Desktop/Routes.sh` (or substitute whatever your login name is for `Austin`).

Comment: Thank you, it still is not working though. I can not even run the .sh file manually without opening the CLI and doing it with sudo and typing my password in. If I try to open with > CLI, it says "Broken Pipe" and "Permission Denied Logout." Because of this, I assume the same issue is likely occurring when the system tries to automate the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run commands that require root privileges. You can't do that using a launch agent that runs as your user.

You can do it using a login script. A login script runs as root, after you have authenticated. See [“Customizing Login and Logout”](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html) to learn how to set up a login script.